# Replace an element in the_content() with wp_title()

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to replace an element in `the_content()` with `wp_title()`.

EDIT: the data bellow is stored in the_content() function. This is an wordpress function that shows post's content.

Here is example of `the_content()`

```
</h2>
<ol>
<li>element_1</li>
```

I want to make it:

```
</h2>
<ol>
<li>wp_title()</li>
<li>element_1</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
</h2>
<ol>
    <li>wp_title()</li>
    <li>element_1</li>
```

to

```
</h2>
<ol>
    <li><?php wp_title(); ?></li>
    <li>element_1</li>
```

and you should be good.

Comment: I didn't explain it clearly, all this data is inside a wordpress function the_content(). How do i perform replace on this wordpress function.

Comment: try `print_r` on $GLOBALS... maybe wordpress was nice enough to set a variable for you in the outer loop that calls the content.

Comment: Seen some docs that indicate that `<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>` may work here is not there is a custom filter option described towards the bottom [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/post-title-inside-the_content)

Comment: What did you end up doing... I will update the answer to help the next guy